# How does Oracle decide which blocks are absent in buffer cache for a query?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-performance, database-administration, sqlperformance

Assume that we executed the following query.

```
select * from employees where salary > 10000;
```

After some time, we executed the following query.

```
select * from employees where salary > 500;
```

The second one tend to return more blocks. But we already have some of these blocks in the buffer cache because of the previous query. Maybe some of them are deleted form the buffer cache, but some or all the blocks from the first query may still exist there. So here, the database server should know which blocks already exist and which ones to read from the disc additionally.

My question is, how does the database find and decide which blocks to read from the disc additionally?

Answer (score 3):

Oracle uses the **LRU technique** ( which stands for **'least recently used'**). It is a computer algorithm used to manage data in a cache. When a cache becomes full and you need space for new things - you discard the least recently used items first (things you haven't used for a while but are in the cache consuming space).

It is not specific to data blocks - and data blocks are not really kept in an LRU list, they are managed by a touch count these days - but that touch count algorithm is very much like an LRU so you can think of it that way.

In short, when you hear LRU, think of a cache that manages some data (any data), and tends to discard items from the cache based on whether they have been used recently or not. The more recently something has been used - the more likely it is to stay in the cache.

Each block has a DBA - data block address - that consists of a file# and block#. This uniquely identifies a block in a database. Oracle uses that "key" to identify the block in the buffer cache.

If you run a query, if some blocks are not in the cache, it is because the LRU has cleared them in order to allocate more things that are more recently used. It is not guarantee, but if you need that kind of guarantee, you can use different pools in the buffer cache, mainly you can use the `KEEP` pool to maintain frequently accessed segments in the buffer cache.

Hope it clarifies.

Comment: @oramas, any doubts about the answer ?